# Using ffmpeg with C++: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg

I'm dealing with one example of FFMPEG called is "muxing.c".

So I tried to compile that file with two Makefiles. The first one is for C-language:

```
FFMPEG_LIBS=    libavdevice                        \
                libavformat                        \
                libavfilter                        \
                libavcodec                         \
                libswresample                      \
                libswscale                         \
                libavutil                          \

CFLAGS := -Wall -g $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(FFMPEG_LIBS)) $(CFLAGS)
LDLIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs $(FFMPEG_LIBS)) -lm $(LDLIBS)

SOURCES=        muxing                             \

OBJS=$(addsuffix .o,$(SOURCES))

all: $(OBJS) $(SOURCES)
```

That makefile compiles well. But if I trying to move this code to C++: I rename muxing.c to muxing.cpp and use this Makefile:

```
CC=g++

FFMPEG_LIBS=    libavdevice                        \
                libavformat                        \
                libavfilter                        \
                libavcodec                         \
                libswresample                      \
                libswscale                         \
                libavutil                          \

CPPFLAGS := -Wall -g $(shell pkg-config --cflags $(FFMPEG_LIBS)) $(CPPFLAGS)
LDLIBS := $(shell pkg-config --libs $(FFMPEG_LIBS)) -lm $(LDLIBS)

SOURCES=        muxing                             \

OBJS=$(addsuffix .o,$(SOURCES))

all: $(OBJS) $(SOURCES)
```

I get a bunch of error like this:

```
$ g++   muxing.o  -L/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.4/lib -lavdevice -lavformat -lavfilter -lavcodec -lswresample -lswscale -lavutil  -lm -o muxing
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "av_dict_set(AVDictionary**, char const*, char const*, int)", referenced from:
      _main in muxing.o
  "av_strerror(int, char*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      av_make_error_string(char*, unsigned long, int) in muxing.o
  "avio_closep(AVIOContext**)", referenced from:
      _main in muxing.o
  "swr_convert(SwrContext*, unsigned char**, int, unsigned char const**, int)", referenced from:
      write_audio_frame(AVFormatContext*, OutputStream*) in muxing.o
  "av_dict_copy(AVDictionary**, AVDictionary const*, int)", referenced from:
      open_video(AVFormatContext*, AVCodec*, OutputStream*, AVDictionary*) in muxing.o
      open_audio(AVFormatContext*, AVCodec*, OutputStream*, AVDictionary*) in muxing.o
  "av_dict_free(AVDictionary**)", referenced from:
      open_video(AVFormatContext*, AVCodec*, OutputStream*, AVDictionary*) in muxing.o
      open_audio(AVFormatContext*, AVCodec*, OutputStream*, AVDictionary*) in muxing.o
  "av_rescale_q(long long, AVRational, AVRational)", referenced from:
      write_audio_frame(AVFormatContext*, OutputStream*) in muxing.o
  "av_compare_ts(long long, AVRational, long long, AVRational)", referenced from:
      _main in muxing.o
      get_video_frame(OutputStream*) in muxing.o
      get_audio_frame(OutputStream*) in muxing.o
```

Is that mean those libs are not ready to work with x64? I strongly need to mix that code (muxing.c) with my C++ code because I have to render a video on the fly using ImageMagick (my code was written with C++) for the frames.

How can I mix C++ and C in this case?

My env is: OS X 10.12.3

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, Is that make sense? :) That order of libs works fine with C but doesn't works in CPP-mode :)

Comment: If the ffmpeg headers aren't wrapped with `extern "C"`, you'll get name mangling issues with C++.  But also, C and C++ are different languages, and C++ is not a perfect superset of C... so you really shouldn't simply rename a C source file and compile as C++.

Comment: The `g++` command that was actually run in your example is just *linking*, not compiling - surely you need to *compile* with a C++ compiler first? Your Makefile doesn't contain any file with `.cpp` extension.